# GWT CellTable sorting - how to use sorted values?

Tags: java, sorting, gwt

I've created a `ListHandler` and I'm overiding its `setComparator` method to provide a basic alphabetical sort of each `TextColumn` in my `CellTable`.

Here's an example of one such sort:

```
private void createTargetColumnSortHandler()
    {
    ListHandler<RegradeRule> targetColumnHandler = new ListHandler<RegradeRule>(resultsTableDataProvider.getList());
    targetColumnHandler.setComparator(this.targetPromotionColumn, new Comparator<RegradeRule>()
        {
        @Override
        public int compare(RegradeRule o1, RegradeRule o2)
            {
            if (o1 == o2)
                {
                return 0;
                }
            // Compare the name columns.
            if (o1 != null)
                {
                return (o2 != null) ? o1.getTargetPromotion().compareTo(o2.getTargetPromotion()) : 1;
                }
            return -1;
            }
        });
    this.resultsTable.addColumnSortHandler(targetColumnHandler);
    }
```

In the GUI, after clicking a column to initiate a sort, how can I retrieve the sorted values? Or to rephrase, what stores the sorted values? When debugging I can't seem to catch this click event (or can't find a suitable `breakpoint`), therefore I can't find the sorted values - for example, if it's the `ListDataProvider` used in my `CellTable`

**Edit**
The CellTable is rendering the sorted values perfectly. I just want to use the sorted values and export to Excel (I can export the un-sorted values just fine)

Comment: once columnsort event is triggered, you can trigger a asynchronous event to get data from dao layer and render in UI

Comment: At this point, the CellTable already has its values retrieved from an asynchronous service - so the columnsort event doesn't need to trigger any asynchronous calls. Is there a return value of the columnsort event, if so, can I get it?

Comment: Also, The CellTable is rendering the sorted values perfectly. I just want to use the sorted values and export to Excel (I can export the un-sorted values just fine). Sorry - edited question to explain that.

Comment: `resultsTableDataProvider.getList()` will contain sorted list.

Comment: Thanks - it does. That answers my question of where the sorted values are stored.

Comment: Not sure if I can link an answer to your comment.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer. I'm glad I could help ;)

Comment: Yes, I feel quite foolish! (Lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ListHandler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/ColumnSortEvent.ListHandler.html) will sort the list that you provide in the constructor. You have passed the list backed by the [`ListDataProvider`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/ListDataProvider.html), so you will find your sorted list there:

`resultsTableDataProvider.getList();`